# String converted to a function command for global-set-key (elisp)

Tags: string, emacs, elisp

I would like to call global-set-key in a function, giving it arguments, to create global-set-keys.

```
(defun global-setter (arg1 arg2)
 (global-set-key arg1 '(concat "example" arg1 arg2))
)

(global-setter "*" "^")
```

This should create the binding that when pressing `*`, the function `example-*^` should be called.

I can't figure out how to get the string to be passed as a function / command name. What am I doing wrong?

So far I tried combinations of `` `',@ ``, `(intern)`, `(eval)`, `(function)` but I have no idea what I should be doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason your code doesn't work is because you quoted the (concat ..) expression so it's never evaluated. And global-set-key expects a lambda or a symbol.

You can construct a symbol using intern, then provide the symbol to set-key:

```
(defun my-test () (interactive) (message "ok"))
(global-set-key "\C-c!" (intern (concat "my" "-" "test")))
```

Note that any function called via global-set-key and variants must be **interactive**.

Comment: I can only say that I must have missed this specific combination of lack of `'`. This does really seem to make sense now, though. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use `lexical-let` to define a [*closure*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29), an anonymous function that references values from the environment in which it was defined:

```
(defun global-setter (arg1 arg2)
  (lexical-let ((arg1 arg1) (arg2 arg2))
    (global-set-key arg1 (lambda ()
                           (interactive)
                           (concat "example" arg1 arg2)))))
```

Emacs 24 [natively supports](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Lexical-Binding.html) lexical binding and closures, so `lexical-let` is no longer necessary:

```
(defun global-setter (arg1 arg2)
  (global-set-key arg1 (lambda ()
                         (interactive)
                         (concat "example" arg1 arg2))))
```

For this to work, be sure to set `lexical-binding` to `t` in your `.emacs` and add this to the end of the file to ensure lexical-binding is used for byte-compilation:

```
;; Local Variables:
;; lexical-binding: t
;; End:
```

Comment: It is not working though unfortunately. Did you test this with creating a function called `example-*^`? I suspect it does not work because once you call the function, it does not have arg1 / arg2 included (and can therefore not concat them). Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Dualinity The closure is much more powerful than constructing the function name — you can do *anything* with arg1 and arg2 in the closure. (In my case I showed how to call the `concat` function because I understood that that's what you wanted to do. The example didn't make much sense as `concat` is side-effect-free, though.) If you only want to dynamically construct the *name* of the function, Joost's answer is the way to go.